# Play Framework 2: Read the application version defined in Build.scala

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, version

I use the Play Framework 2.0 (2.0.3).
I have a Java project and want to read the application version (`appVersion`) defined in Build.scala.

What I already saw is that it's possible to read certain configuration details from the `Application` object provided to Global.java, but didn't find a key called appVersion or similar.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can define the version in `application.conf` and let `Build.scala` read the value. I did this with the version number and application name. The following works in Play 2.0, there is an updated [solution for Play 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430088/play-framework-2-1-use-play-api-configuration-in-build-scala).

In `project/Build.scala`, load the configuration and get the properties:

```
val conf = play.api.Configuration.load(new File("."))
val appName    = conf.getString("app.name").getOrElse("unnamed application")
val appVersion = conf.getString("app.version").getOrElse("0.0.0")
```

In `conf/application.conf` define the properties:

```
app.version = 1.0
app.name = My Application
```

Finally in your application it will be accessible with

```
 Play.application().configuration().getString("app.version")
```

---

The configuration syntax has quite some features, so you can even go a little more crazy with your version or application names:

```
app {
  major    = 1
  minor    = 2
  revision = 3
  version = ${app.major}.${app.minor}.${app.revision}
  name = My Application ${app.major}.${app.minor}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! You probably meant Build.scala and not build.conf?

Comment: Any idea how to make this work in Play 2.1? I'm getting the same error as this person: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430088/play-framework-2-1-use-play-api-configuration-in-build-scala

Answer (score 18):

I use the [SBT BuildInfo plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) for this purpose:

```
import sbtbuildinfo.Plugin._

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA, settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ buildInfoSettings).settings(

  buildInfoKeys := Seq[Scoped](name, appVersion, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),
  buildInfoPackage := "org.foo.bar",

  ...

)
```

This generates an `org.foo.bar.BuildInfo` object which you can then call from the source code:

```
org.foo.bar.BuildInfo.version
```

You can also define custom keys in the build and add them to the buildInfoKeys, which is quite useful if your build gets more complex.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the current version of Play by using:

```
play.core.PlayVersion.current();
```

Comment: Hi, I want to know the version of my application and not the version of Play.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible, since the Build.scala file is only used for the build, not at runtime

Comment: No problem, ok, in that case what would be your recommendation, that I have to set the application version only once?

Comment: Yes, I would set the app version in the Global object (as a static property for instance): http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/JavaGlobal

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can get Play application version and application name defined in your **build.sbt**

```
name := "myApp"
version :="1.0.4"
```

**Notice this only works in PROD mode.** In dev mode SBT shares a JVM instance with the application and those calls return something different.

```
Application.class.getPackage().getImplementationTitle());     // returns "myApp"
Application.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());    // returns "1.0.4"
```

In this case Application class is a class defined in your project. It can be any class from your project.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that this method doesn't work out of the box for Play >=2.4.x

To fix the problem add this to your build.sbt

```
packageOptions += Package.ManifestAttributes(
  "Implementation-Version" -> (version in ThisBuild).value,
  "Implementation-Title" -> name.value
)
```

The two properties will be appended to MANIFEST.FM file in your build so the package title and version can be read from the code.

fyi: I use SBT native packager

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.3")
```

Comment: This returned 2.4.6 (Play version) for me.

Comment: Make sure you use PROD mode `sbt start` and the class you are using to get the package is in your code.