# Play Framework 2.1: Use play.api.Configuration in Build.scala

Tags: java, playframework, version, playframework-2.1

In the top answer to [Play Framework 2: Read the application version defined in Build.scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369967/play-framework-2-read-the-application-version-defined-in-build-scala) it's suggested that the application version number be specified in `conf/application.conf` and loaded in `Build.scala` through `play.api.Configuration`. I'm using `Play 2.1-RC2` and getting the following error message when building:

```
[error] [...]/project/Build.scala:7: object Configuration is not a member of package play.api 
[error] val conf = play.api.Configuration.load(new File("."))
```

I think this might be caused by the fact that with Play 2.1 build dependencies have to be specified as plugins to SBT, and `play.api.Configuration` is not part of Play's SBT plugin. I'm guessing I have to include Play's core libraries in `project/plugins.sbt`, but I haven't been able to figure out how. Any ideas?

(note: Would have made this a comment in the original question if I had enough rep points)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I works in `2.1-RC2` if you use typesafe's config library directly, without Play's `Configuration` wrapper. It's a Java API, so it is used slightly different than described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12377155/897024).

In `project/Build.scala` import the library:

```
import com.typesafe.config._
```

and load the configuration from the file manually. Calling `resolve()` is needed to resolve substitutions.

```
val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

val appName    = conf.getString("app.name")
val appVersion = conf.getString("app.version")
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Apologies for the late response.

Comment: Be careful! Don't use dots and spaces in the `appName` of the play-2.1.x. Or say hello to `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`.

Comment: @kapep : would you like to see this question and eventually suggest something? http://stackoverflow.com/q/21133830/1066240