# How to get application name and version only on command line in Play 2.1

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1

According to [this nice trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14581996/1066240) I'm setting version and after command `play normalized-name version` in console get the output like

```
[info] Loading project definition from /www/apps/MyApp/project
[info] Set current project to MyApp (in build file:/www/apps/MyApp/)
[info] myapp
[info] 1.2.3
```

Anyway for deployment automatization I'd need to get only concated values like `myapp-1.2.3` or at least only value `myapp` and `1.2.3` (without *Loading* info *[info]* prefixes) how can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can easily disable the prefixes and logging info. I would use a shell script to extract the name and version from the output.

Comment: @kapep Thx for info, I'm afraid that won't work especially when using for many instances/apps. For now I'm finding `myapp-1.2.3.zip` as an only file in `dist` so I can use it for further processing, anyway it would be nice to get other data from play console :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use SBT 0.13 [that's only available since Play 2.2](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Highlights22) so your mileage may vary.

In `build.sbt` define a task that prints out the `version` setting.

```
lazy val showVersion = taskKey[Unit]("Show version")

showVersion := {
  println(version.value)
}
```

Tweak it to include other settings like `normalizedName` (aka `normalized-name`).

With the `showVersion` task, run the following command to get the version:

```
$ play --error 'set showSuccess := false' showVersion
0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

You may want to add `showSuccess := false` to `build.sbt` to make the command shorter - see [How to turn off info and success messages in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20817292/1305344)

Comment: Thx, I need to keep your answer in mind while we'll be ready to switch milestone in project!

Comment: Do you want me to downgrade it to SBT 0.12/Play 2.1 or you do it yourself? Hint, hint: accept the answer :)

Comment: Och no, no I'll check it here, dzięki ;)