# How get application version in play framework and build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm using play 2.2 with Scala, how can I get version from build.sbt?

```
name := "project_name"
version := "0.2-SNAPSHOT"

play.Project.playScalaSettings
```

or how can I pass there value from another object?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've added this to my build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

version := conf.getString("app.version")
```

and in my application.conf:

```
app.version="0.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the solution using the `application.conf` to keep version info (you must to modify it to fit 2.2 build file): [Play Framework 2: Read the application version defined in Build.scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369967/play-framework-2-read-the-application-version-defined-in-build-scala)

When you have it in `application.conf` you can read it easily in your controller.