# Loading external settings in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to add an sbt plugin to a play application.

The plugin requires some configuration since it needs to connect to a database. These are the settings that the plugin requires in the build.sbt file:

```
 jooqOptions := Seq("jdbc.driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                    "jdbc.url" -> "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fnord",
                    "jdbc.user" -> "fnord",
                    "jdbc.password" -> "fnord",
                    "generator.database.name" -> "org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase",
                    "generator.database.inputSchema" -> "fnord",
                    "generator.target.packageName" -> "com.myproject.jooq")
```

Since the user and password will depent on the specific machine on which i deploy the app, i would like to load them from somewhere where each user can assign the user and password himself.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it using the accepted solution from:

[How get application version in play framework and build.sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371784/how-get-application-version-in-play-framework-and-build-sbt)

I've added this to my build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.config._

val conf = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("conf/application.conf")).resolve()

version := conf.getString("app.version")
```

and in my application.conf:

```
app.version="0.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to read them from an environment variable, another to have a config file of some kind in a predefined path that you load and read in your sbt project.

Since the sbt config is scala code you can for example use `sys.env` to read environment variables.
You can find the [scaladoc for sys.env here](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.package@env:scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String])