# Play Framework: Reading Version from Build.sbt

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've been seeing a bunch of questions about how to read a version from build.sbt, and there have been a lot of work-arounds provided for how to point build.sbt to conf/application.conf and have the version specified in conf/application.conf instead.

I have a Configuration object that needs to get in the version. I currently have it set up like this ([How get application version in play framework and build.sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371784/how-get-application-version-in-play-framework-and-build-sbt)), where the Configuration objects from application.conf. However, I'd still like to get it directly from build.sbt. How can I do that? Should I perhaps run a bash command on the build.sbt file to get the version from there? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at sbt-buildinfo, it might help you

Comment: I tried to use that, but when I imported the package I got a weird error (I cannot remember what it was, it was a few hours ago). Edit: this error "sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.eed3si9n#sbt-buildinfo;0.5.0: not found"

Comment: I use `MyClass.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` for this. But it works only in a distribution - not during development.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We managed to get information via build-info, here's some detail configuration.

1. Add plugins (we also include sbt-git since we want git version as well) into `project/plugins.sbt`

   ```
   addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.8.4")
   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.5.0")
   ```
2. Configure plugins in `build.sbt`

   ```
   enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)

   enablePlugins(GitVersioning)

   buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](organization, name, version, BuildInfoKey.action("gitVersion") {       
      git.formattedShaVersion.?.value.getOrElse(Some("Unknown")).getOrElse("Unknown") +"@"+ git.formattedDateVersion.?.value.getOrElse("")        
   })

   buildInfoPackage := "version"
   ```
3. Within views (*.html.scala), display those info simply by

   ```
   Version @version.BuildInfo.version - build @version.BuildInfo.gitVersion
   ```
4. Or you can just using all values from BuildInfo in your java or scala code, by calling `version.BuildInfo.XX`

Comment: So I didn't update, but I managed to get this working last week. Basically, I have to bring all plugins internal, to the project. The problem was mapping build-info internally to the application. Once it was brought in correctly and everything mapped out internally correctly (time consuming and dealing with paths), then was able to get quickly get it working.

Comment: Updated versions for plugins.sbt:
`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-buildinfo" % "0.10.0");
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "1.0.2")`

Code for build.sbt

`lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .enablePlugins(BuildInfoPlugin)
  .enablePlugins(GitVersioning)
  .settings(
    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, BuildInfoKey.action("gitVersion") { ...omitted from above...   }),
    buildInfoPackage := "buildInfoArticle"
  )`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not quite what you want but some time ago I used such workaround (I needed version for additional deployment steps): I created file like `app-version.cfg` in the main app directory, so I could use it within `build.sbt` like:

```
version := scala.io.Source.fromFile("app-version.cfg").mkString
```

and in Unix bash:

```
version=`cat app-version.cfg`
```