# Is it possible to save version, name of build app on typesafe activator dist

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator

I need to echo version of app in file like VERSION after 
run `activator dist`.
I can't understand how to run script in build.sbt and gets settings.name and settings.version
And where put the code to build.sbt
And need to add the file VERSION to zip...

Comment: Not directly, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35159750/1066240

Comment: hmm. found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371784/how-get-application-version-in-play-framework-and-build-sbt interesting variant