# How to determine currently running Play version?

Tags: java, playframework, version

Is there some easy way of retrieving the currently running version of Play framework for an application? I was hoping there is something like `Play.getVersion()` which would return "2.3.6" if the application is running version 2.3.6.

The only way I've found so far is the do something like

```
System.out.println(((HashMap<String, Object>)Play.application().configuration().getObject("java")).get("class"));
```

which gives me all jars loaded for my application, and I can check if e.g. play_2.11-2.3.6.jar is loaded.

Please tell me there is a better way?

Answer (score 3):

To get play version, you can use

```
play.core.PlayVersion.current();
```

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371679